# Ionic 4 to prevent to change page when Loading is present

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

i am having tough time to solve my problem. In Ionic 4 **ionViewCanLeave** was removed and changed to Angular's Route Guards.
It's good decision until i get this problem.

In Ionic3 i can prevent page change *when back button is pressed* with this simple code

```
    from: any = null;
    canLeave: boolean = true;
    loading: any; 

    ionViewCanLeave(): boolean {
        // prevent change page when (this.canLeave == false)
        return this.canLeave;
    }

    doLogin() {
        this.loginFormSubmit = true;


        this.loadingPresent();
        this.userProvider.login(this.userLogin)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.loading.dismiss();
                this.canLeave = true;
                // page can change because (this.canLeave == true) now
            })

    }

    loadingPresent() {
        // when loading controller is show can't change page because (this.canLeave == false)
        this.canLeave = false;
        this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: 'Loading...'
        });
        this.loading.onDidDismiss(() => {
            this.canLeave = true;
        });
        this.loading.present();
    }
```

And because Ionic4 using Angular's Route Guards, **CanActivate** and **CanDeactivate** is placed on another file, how to implement to prevent change page like Ionic3 ? And if i use **CanDeactivate** how to detect if loading controller is present in angular guard?

Comment: so in this scenario what I did in my project is I moved 'loaders' to be a dedicated service available to any component that needs it including route guard. It actually have me some other benefits so it was OK change. Not sure if you can solve this in other way though

Answer (score 0):

Angular **CanDeactivate** guard allows you to implement the same functionality as *ionViewCanLeave()* in Ionic 3. The key here is that the route component instance is imported into the canDeactivate method in the guard class. This way you can access the component properties and methods. For example:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<YourComponent> {
  canDeactivate(component: YourComponent, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState: RouterStateSnapshot) {
 
    // you could call your component ionViewCanLeave and return its value
    // return component.ionViewCanLeave();
    
    // or simply return its canLeave property directly
    return component.canLeave;
  }

}
```